# ArcGIS Online Web Map only showing OBJECTID for Feature Class

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-layer

I published a series of Feature Layers to ArcGIS Online.  When I try to open the REST endpoint in my browser, it is showing ONLY the OBJECTID field for each layer, even though all of them have multiple attributes.

Why is it only showing one field and how do I resolve that?

EDIT: I should add that all of the feature classes are joined to non-spatial data in other tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely need to export each feature class, while joined, to a new feature class in order to see the attributes. I don't think the joined attributes will show up in ArcGIS Online.The joined data needs to be made permanent in order to view it.

Comment: I found a similar post: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/37165.  Assuming that's correct, then Joins are not supported.